# Compound Collider Trigger

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a parent object, which has four children cubes. The parent has rigidbody, no collider. The four cubes only have colliders, which trigger tags are set true. I want to handle collision in the parent object. However, it didn't work. I know use onCollisionEnter may work, but I must use trigger.  Could anybody give me some ideas?

Comment: if the parent object has no collider, how do you expect it to get collisions? Your script must be connected to a rigidbody (or a collider) in order to work.

Comment: The Unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger colliders are unable to use OnColliderEnter because things pass through them instead of colliding. If you wish to detect when an object enters a trigger collider, use OnTriggerEnter instead.
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

If however you wish to keep the trigger colliders and make them collide only with specific kind of objects, you can add a second set of colliders that are not triggers and use layers to differentiate which objects can collide with them and which ones pass through. You can then go to Edit->Project Settings->Physics and at the bottom at Layer Collision Matrix configure which layers can collide with each other.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html